# Pointing to the 11th element in an array with 10 elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let's say you have an int arr[] with 10 elements, and an int * ptr. 
I thought that the following lines would cause an error but instead it prints 0 as the value stored in ptr. How did it calculate it as 0?

```
ptr = arr;//ptr currently points to the first element in arr
ptr = (arr + 10);//points to what would be the llth element in memory for arr
printf("ptr %p\n", ptr);//this displays where the 11th element would be in memory
printf("*ptr %i\n", *ptr);//why would this print 0?
```

Answer (score 6):

Accessing an array out of bounds is **undefined behavior**. That means anything can happen, like crashing, or printing out 0 or any other number, you just can't tell beforehand what actually will happen.

That's exactly why **undefined behavior** is so evil, you might not even notice that something is wrong since it seems to be working correctly. You might even get the correct result in your calculation when you try to test it and it might give you something wrong the next time you run it.

Comment: Does it use pointer arithmetic to figure that out, or is it something else?

Comment: It uses pointer arithmetic to get the address, and pointing to the element past the end is legal. But once you try to dereference it you are in undefined behavior lands.

Answer (score 1):

Note that ANSI C requires that if you define:

```
SomeType array[10];
```

then the address `&array[10]` (equivalent to `array + 10`) must be a valid address.  However, it is not permitted to dereference that valid address; doing that invokes undefined behaviour and anything could happen.  That said, the most common behaviour is that some other variable gets read, but you can't a priori tell which other variable, and it might be the return address of the function or something else unexpected.

As a consequence of this, you could run a loop like this:

```
SomeType *end = array + 10;

for (SomeType *src = array; src < end; src++)
{
    ...use `*src` to reference the current row of the array...
}
```

Another consequence is that there are limits on what can be placed at the very top of addressable memory.  However, such issues are seldom of concern (unless you're working on embedded microcomputers with very small memories).